# get position of 2D array of JLabels

Tags: arrays, object, 2d, mouseevent, jlabel

First post here but long time reader, been searching through but cant find a post that exactly helps my problem.

I am trying to create 2D grid of JLabels with mouselisteners and retrieve the X / Y position of the clicked JLabel but cant find a way to do it. I have tried a few ways I found out on this site but nothing is working.

currently I have the following....

```
        pcenter.setLayout(new GridLayout(game.getXSize(), game.getYSize()));
    pcenter.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8,8,8,8));
    pcenter.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((game.getXSize() * 30), (game.getYSize() * 30)));
    gamegrid = new JLabel[game.getXSize()][game.getYSize()];
    for ( int i = 0; i < game.getXSize(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < game.getYSize(); j++) {
            gamegrid[i][j] = new JLabel();
            gamegrid[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));
            gamegrid[i][j].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                }
            });
            pcenter.add(gamegrid[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

'game' is an object that houses a 2D array of objects for which i want to pass in the same co-ordinates of the JLabel clicked. E.G clicking on gamegrid[2][5] will contact game.plots[2][5].

whenever i try and make a variable to store 2 and 5 it wants to make the method FINAL, and if I put the method inside the MouseAdapter() it wants to make 'i' or 'j' FINAL.

please help :) thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out! I'll post here just encase someone else would like to know.

I created 3 other variables in the class:

```
private static Object source;
private static int currentX, currentY;
```

then the current MouseListener, where it is now, I added the following:

```
        for ( int i = 0; i < game.getXSize(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < game.getYSize(); j++) {

            gamegrid[i][j] = new JLabel();
            gamegrid[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));
            gamegrid[i][j].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                    source = e.getSource();  //added this to get the mouseevent object.
                    XYsource();  // this is a method to turn the object source 
                                    into X and Y coords.

                }
            });
            pcenter.add(gamegrid[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

and finally the following method to turn the Object source into the X and Y co-ordinates

```
    public static void XYsource() {

    int maxX = game.getXSize();
    int maxY = game.getYSize();

    for(int i = 0; i < maxX; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < maxY; j++){
            if (gamegrid[i][j] == source) {
                currentX = i;
                currentY = j;
            }
        }
    }

    updateXY();   // this is just a method to set text on the screen showing 
                     the X and Y coordinates to test the MouseListener
}
```